# Problemas con z-Index

Tags: css, magento

tengo una plantilla premiun en magento he ido tocándola según requerimientos pero hace poco me pidieron añadir un plugin de etiquetas en el mismo y desde entonces me ha descuadrado muchas cosas en el front por temas del z-index.

[image: se monta por encima de los demás elementos haciendo que todo se descuadre o no sea clickeable]

[image: en todos los elementos me daña el diseño]

He revisando documentación del plugin y de mi theme pero no he logrado mucho, he visto las clases y les he forzado otros z-index inclusive incluyendolos en mi .less y volviendo a compilar con grunt y se sigue viendo igual.

el link esta en abautista.site

si alguien logra ver algo que yo no se loa agradeceria enormemente.

Comment: Las cards tienen estilos en linea, revisa tu JS a ver si no los esta agregando por ahi

Comment: Tienes muchos estilos en lines que debes revisar pero para que corrijas el header fijo agregale a tu archivo de estilos CSS  la regla: .header.header8.active-sticky.middle-header-content {z-index:999999;  }

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: A ver... Lo primero que haría, en tu lugar, es desinstalar el nuevo módulo y comprobar que realmente es el causante de este problema, ya que dices que han habido varias modificaciones. Tras comprobar el resultado, actuaría en consecuencias, pero sin código es prácticamente imposible que te digamos algo concreto. Este trabajo trata más de ser detective que programador.